# Angular: Http vs fetch api

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, http

Although I understand the way Angular makes HTTP requests, I prefer using the built-in Fetch API because I don't have to subscribe and unsubscribe just to make 1 simple request. I tried using it in my angular app and it didn't throw any errors, page didn't reload (still a SPA), everything worked fine. I suppose there is a time and place for everything.

This:

```
fetch('/api/get_post_by_id/1').then(r => r.json()).then(j => { console.log(j); });
```

Is more simple, than this:

```
const obs = this.http.get('/api');
obs.subscribe(() => { ... });
obs.unsubscribe();
```

Basically my question is, is it wrong to use the Fetch API when developing Angular apps?

Comment: It isn't wrong, it's just that angular integrates better with its native client because everything in angular is done in the reactive paradigm. The fetch api simply returns a promise which is fine and dandy. Your question though is too open ended

Comment: `this.http.get('/api').subscribe(j => console.log(j));` <= You made it too complicated, this is all you need and it is similar to the code you have for `window.fetch`. You can use the generic version and it will be typed to the expected interface as well making it even easier.

Comment: I think Angular http complete observable after the request so you don't need to unsubscribe it every time and you could use the power of RxJS operators.

Comment: that was my whole thing: unsubscribing. If Angular actually completes the observable then that is great. That was my biggest pain-point. thanks for mentioning that @ptesser

Comment: To me the deal-breaker is that `fetch` returns a `Promise` which enables the use of `async`/`await`, so that we can eliminate those nasty nested callbacks. That and being built-in into Javascript now.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Like any tool you encounter during development each tool will have advantages and disadvantages and it's good to think about why a tool is being used.

When we take a look at `HttpClient` it originally simplified the mess that was `XMLHttpRequest`. In the same way `$.ajax` originally did it, `HttpClient` was the 'angular solution'. It followed the ideology of everything being an observable which has advantages (you can mix and match it with other observables) and disadvantages (it adds a lot of bloat).

## Advantages of `HttpClient`

- It allows easy mixing and matching of two observables (e.g. let's say you have one observable which returns multiple times and an API request which returns once and you want to zip the two together it's trivially easy to do). Of course, turning a promise into an observable only requires importing `from` from `rxjs`
- If you forget adding an abstraction - having all requests going through an `apiService` layer - you can still use an interceptor to achieve similar results magically.
- It will increase the learning curve for new Angular developers, thus making your job more special.
- `HttpClient` does some magic for you such as automatic retrying of requests.
- It's already included in Angular, so if you need to support 7 year old browsers like IE11 you don't need to load a polyfill like with `fetch`.

## Advantages of `fetch`

**Important** : All fetch related code assumes you do create a very simple abstraction (e.g. `apiService` in these examples). This is the same as setting up an interceptor in `HttpClient`-land.

- It's the new industry standard. Once you know it, it can be used anywhere (most likely once Angular and React die - which at some point they will - `fetch` will still most likely be around).
- It simplifies working with service workers as the `Request` and `Response` objects are the same you are using in your normal code.
- HTTP requests will typically return once and only once (of course you might be loading a file chunk by chunk, but that's a very rare exception to the rule). `fetch` is built around the norm (single return values), not the exception (multiple return values), and thus returns a `Promise` rather than a stream-like-type. The advantage this results in is that it plays nicely with any and all relevant new language features such as `async` and `await`. Compare:

  ```
   try {
       const posts = await this.apiService.get('/posts');
       // work with posts
   } catch (error) {
       // handle error
   }
   console.log('this happens **after** the request completes');
  ```

  with

  ```
   this.http.get('/posts')
       .subscribe(posts => {
           // work with posts
       })
       .catch(error => {
           // work with error
       });
   console.log('this happens **before** the request completes');
  ```

  (of course you can also `toPromise` each Observable that will complete (or add `.pipe(take(1))`, but that's frankly a bunch of superfluous code (which I still often end up using))
- It simplifies onboarding of new people. When you see a request such as

  ```
   this.apiService.get('/posts');
  ```

  a developer from any framework can come and right-click on `.get` and check out the function definition where things such as a domain and an authentication header being added will be clearly defined.

  On the other hand when a developer sees

  ```
   this.http.get('/posts')
  ```

  they have no way of easily discovering if and where the request might be changed unless they are aware of Angular specific magic. This is one of the reasons why Angular is considered to have a steep learning curve.
- There is no risk of there being magic you aren't aware of such as automatic retrying of requests which can end up in the same request triggering 4 times on the server and you having no idea how that's possible.
- It's already included in the browser - provided you don't need to support 7 year old browsers - so it can result in a slightly smaller bundle size.

## Complete tie

- I sincerely don't see how types are a difference, as typing a return value from any method can be done. `<Model>this.apiService.get('/posts')` works perfectly fine.

## Conclusion

Personally, I would strongly recommend anybody to use `fetch` with an abstraction layer. It results in easier to read code (even a junior who hasn't ever seen `async` and `await` is able to read it) and even if you are in a rare situation where your `apiService` has to return multiple times you are still completely free to do so as you're fully in control. And in general, you should only *not* use the standard (`fetch`) if the alternative offers significant advantages. Even if it was a perfect tie in terms of advantages and disadvantages it probably isn't worth going for a 'framework specific' solution.

`HttpClient` just doesn't seem to offer any tangible advantages beyond saving a couple of minutes of time during the initial project setup where you don't need to set up an abstraction layer for API requests.

Comment: Thanks! I really like this answer and I agree with the points you made. Still rather new to angular.

Comment: Why was this voted down?

Slight English quirks and observations Angular fan-boys will argue with are the only reasons I see.

Personally Promises + Fetch API are my preference, but it's not a big deal so I go with the flow.

Comment: @PaulLockwood As is probably obvious English is a second language for me and I have to confess I didn't proofread this post at all. Went through it quickly now, but any and all edits are very welcome.

Comment: @DavidMulder, thank you very much for this review. Very helpful point! I'll go with the abstraction layer using fetch.

Comment: Those who have to support `IE11` will need a polyfill for fetch. It is a striking disadvantage compared to subtle nuances between `from(fetch('/url'))` and `HttpClient`

Comment: @bhantol Trying to understand your point, this answer already states that those who have to support 7 year old browser versions benefit from HTTPClient where you don't need to spend those 5 seconds including a polyfill.

Comment: 5 seconds to include a 3kb polyfill that gets discarded by most browsers most of the time.

Comment: @bhantol You will save more more than 3kb by not loading HTTPClient though, and in addition to that you don't load the polyfill for 99% of users, so under the line it increases loading speeds for all.

Comment: @DavidMulder You are right http-client could be more than fetch especially that I am consuming http events for upload progress. I take it all back

Comment: More reasons for using Angular's http client: Better testing integration and HTTPInterceptors, which are very useful e.g. for logging out a user if an 401 response was returned. See https://angular.io/guide/http#intercepting-requests-and-responses

Comment: @LyteFM Why do you feel like testing integration is better with Angular's http client? If anything I would say it's similarly complex, but non-standard, so harder to learn. And regarding `HttpInterceptor` it once again boils down to the issue of non-discoverability and they are mentioned as the second point for Angular, that if you forget adding an abstraction, they present you a hacky solution.

Comment: I think I misunderstood the way you meant the „If you forget adding a layer...” - part at first, if „magic” wasn't meant in a negative way. And sure, when having previous testing experience in other frameworks but not with Angular, it will be more difficult - but not if having written mainly other Angular-specific tests. On an Angular project, I'd prefer working with a codebase that clearly follows the documentation over one that encourages custom solutions closer to web standards - also from a learner's perspective.

Comment: @LyteFM 'Magic' is definitely meant in a negative way, because it means that you *need* the documentation in addition to the code, even as an experienced developer. That's not to say that magical solution aren't sometimes worth it. They totally can be worth it, but they have to offer benefits significantly greater than the non-magical solution. The benefits of the non-magical way are mostly that your IDE understands what's happening and you can simply follow the `import` statements.

Comment: `It will increase the learning curve for new Angular developers` This is not an advantage, it's a drawback. Easier to user APIs are generally better, all else being equal.

Comment: @Alejandro The tongue in cheek 'advantage' is in the words you emmitted to quote: "thus making your job more special.". Some of the highest paid jobs are with obsolete technologies with hard, not easy APIs.

Comment: _"It will increase the learning curve for new Angular developers, thus making your job more special."_ - Listing this as an advantage makes me feel good about creating spaghetti code.

Comment: How come no one mentioned ServiceWorkers? You can use them to intercept literally any request made by the browser, not just fetch. It is therefore way more powerful and invalidates the advantage of using an interceptor in Angular. It's even supported by all major browsers.

Comment: @Adrian service workers are great for intercepting requests with the goal of caching them and/or providing offline support, but I have never seen them used for managing sessions and they can't help with standardized error handling (e.g. in our in between layer we automatically show an error dialog (and report the error) whenever most types of our errors are returned by our API)

Comment: @DavidMulder this was a very helpful answer. Can you recommend any open source Angular project(s) that use “fetch()” in a structured way? Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 30):

```
this.http.get('/api').subscribe(j => console.log(j));
```

You made it too complicated, above is all you need and it is similar to the code you have for `window.fetch`. You can use the generic version and it will be typed to the expected interface as well making it even easier.

```
this.http.get<IModel>('/api').subscribe(j => console.log(j));
```

There is no need for `unsubscribe` and you only need to `pipe` + `map` if you want to transform the result before hand. Calling `json()` was required for the "old" HttpModule which has been replaced with (*technically extended by*) `HttpClient` as of version 4.3

---

And if you still prefer `Promise` over an `Observable` you can always call `toPromise()`.

```
this.http.get('/api').toPromise().then(j => console.log(j));
```

See also [HttpClient](https://angular.io/guide/http)

---

> is it wrong to use the Fetch API when developing Angular apps?

It is not wrong but there are reasons not to do it. You can inject `HttpClient` and write comprehensive unit tests for various scenarios, URLs, Http verbs, etc. Doing the same if you have used `window.fetch` throughout your code becomes much more difficult. `HttpClient` is also richer in that you can use the type system for your results. Observables are also more feature rich than Promises and this can come in handy in more complex scenarios like sequencing calls when dealing with multiple micro services or canceling a call if additional user input is received.

So there are multiple reasons to use the `HttpClient` and I can't think of a single one not to besides that it is a small learning curve.

Comment: Thanks! I was new to Angular. This makes sense

Answer (score 8):

So, after 2 years of using Angular, here are some things i found out:

1. There is this library called RxJS - https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/overview, which is written in TypeScript (superset of JavaScript). It is like one of thee best libraries for JavaScript.

Basically, it makes event-driven apps a breeze in JS by using the `Observable` paradigm. A `Promise` can only return a value once and is **async** only. Observables can be used to return a single value OR multiple values and can be sync or async (depending on how you use it), you can add pipes and operators to transform the results before it is used/consumed by the subscriber to it and etc; it gives a functional programming feel to using it, which is great. It is far more feature-rich than promises.

A `subscriber` listens or "subscribes" to and Observable (the `.subscribe()` call on an observable). An Observable emits 3 types of events: `next`, `error`, and `complete`. Next means an event with/without data was emitted, error means there was an error within the event stream, and complete means the event stream has ended and the observable will not emit anymore.

Now, just because there was an error emitted, does not mean the event stream stopped. An event stream is only stopped when the complete event happens. Also, a subscriber can `unsuscribe` from an observable, meaning it will stop listening to the event stream.

2. The `HttpClient` service from Angular is built using RxJS. They basically wrapped it over the old XmlHttpRequest way of making requests - https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/main/packages/common/http/src/xhr.ts#L193.

When you make a request using Angular's HttpClient service, it automatically completes the observable on `ok` response, so there is no needed to call unsuscribe on the observable since it's done anyway; it won't call complete on error response but http calls only response once.

3. Observables don't execute until they are subscribed to; a Promise executes immediately.

I would say Observables are far better to use over Promises; i don't see RxJS leaving any time soon or ever.

Comment: "Observables don't execute until they are subscribed to; a Promise executes immediately." Does that also happen when you make a POST request? If that's the case, then you'd have to subscribe to the observable even if you don't really need the response just to make sure the request is being made.

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to leave this a comment but I'm too new here. For the abstraction you could use HttpBackend for the fetch call and just extend the HttpClient.

```
import { HttpBackend, HttpClient, HttpEvent, HttpHeaders, HttpRequest, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, Observer } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FetchBackend implements HttpBackend {
  handle(req: HttpRequest<any>): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    
    if (!('fetch' in window)) {
      throw new Error(
        `Fetch not supported with this browser`);
    }

    if (req.method === 'JSONP') {
      throw new Error(
        `Attempted to construct Jsonp request without HttpClientJsonpModule installed.`);
    }

    return new Observable((observer: Observer<HttpEvent<any>>) => {
      const request = new Request(req.urlWithParams, { method: req.method});
      fetch(request)
        .then((r) => {
          r.json().then((body) => {
            const headers = new HttpHeaders();
            r?.headers.forEach((value, name) => {
              headers.append(name, value)
            })
            observer.next(new HttpResponse({
              url: r.url,
              status: r.status,
              statusText: r.statusText,
              body: body,
              headers: headers
            }))
          });
        })

    });
  }
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FetchClient extends HttpClient {
  constructor(handler: FetchBackend) {
    super(handler);
  }
}
```

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wojcsu?file=src/app/fetchBackend.ts)

Comment: Heloo @Aaron welcome to the stackoverflow I see you are new here, please read this link to know how to answer a question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer.  thanks!