# Error in console when trying to route to 404 page in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, routes

I'm trying to create a route to a page on Angular when URL address is not correct.

#### Error in console

In my IDE there is no error message.
The only error message I get on console is this:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
     at SingleAppareilComponent.ngOnInit (single-appareil.component.ts:19)
     at callHook (core.js:2526)
     at callHooks (core.js:2495)
     at executeInitAndCheckHooks (core.js:2446)
     at refreshView (core.js:9480)
     at refreshEmbeddedViews (core.js:10590)
     at refreshView (core.js:9489)
     at refreshComponent (core.js:10636)
     at refreshChildComponents (core.js:9261)
     at refreshView (core.js:9515)
```

Below are my files:

- `SingleAppareilComponent`
- `AppModule`
- HTML template for 404 page
- HTML template for `SingleAppareilComponent`
- `AppareilService`

#### `single.appareil.component.ts`

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { AppareilService } from 'services/appareil.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-single-appareil',
  templateUrl: './single-appareil.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./single-appareil.component.scss']
})
export class SingleAppareilComponent implements OnInit {

  name: string = 'Appareil';
  status: string = 'Statut';
  constructor(private appareilService: AppareilService,
              private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    const id = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
    this.name = this.appareilService.getApparreilById(+id).name;
    this.status = this.appareilService.getApparreilById(+id).status;
  }
}
```

#### `app.module.ts`

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppareilComponent } from './appareil/appareil.component';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppareilService } from 'services/appareil.service';
import { AuthComponent } from './auth/auth.component';
import { AppareilViewComponent } from './appareil-view/appareil-view.component';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from 'services/auth.service';
import { SingleAppareilComponent } from './single-appareil/single- 
appareil.component';
import { FourOhFourComponent } from './four-oh-four/four-oh-four.component';
import { HashLocationStrategy, LocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'appareils', component: AppareilViewComponent },
  { path: 'appareils/:id', component: SingleAppareilComponent },
  { path: 'auth', component: AuthComponent },
  { path: '', component: AppareilViewComponent },
  { path: 'not-found', component: FourOhFourComponent },
  { path:'**', redirectTo: '/notfound' }
]

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    AppareilComponent,
    AuthComponent,
    AppareilViewComponent,
    SingleAppareilComponent,
    FourOhFourComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
  ],
  providers: [
    AppareilService,
    AuthService,
    {provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

and it is supposed to display this template:

#### `four-oh-four.component.html`

```
<h2>Erreur 404</h2>
<p>La page que vous cherchez n'existe pas.</p>
```

but instead it displays this one

#### `single-appareil.component.hmtl`

```
<h2>{{ name }}</h2>
<p>Statut : {{ status }}</p>
<a routerLink="/appareils">Retourner à la liste</a>
```

#### `appareil-service.ts`

```
export class AppareilService {
    appareils = [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: 'Machine à laver',
          status: 'éteint'
        },
        {
          id:2,
          name: 'Frigo',
          status: 'allumé'
        },
        {
          id:3,
          name: 'Ordinateur',
          status: 'éteint'
        }
      ];


    getApparreilById(id: number) {
      const appareil = this.appareils.find(
        (appareilObject) =>{
          return appareilObject.id === id;
        }
      );
      return appareil
    }

    switchOnAll() {
        for (let appareil of this.appareils) {
            appareil.status = 'allumé'
        }
    }

    switchOffAll() {
        for (let appareil of this.appareils) {
            appareil.status = 'éteint'
        }
    }
    
    switchOnOne(index: number) {
        this.appareils[index].status = 'allumé';
    }

    switchOffOne(index: number) {
        this.appareils[index].status = 'éteint';
    }
```

Comment: Probably `this.appareilService.getApparreilById(+id)` returns `undefined`. Open your browser's dev tools, go to the debugger, set a breakpoint in `ngOnInit` and debug the service method `this.appareilService.getApparreilById`

Comment: Would help to see your `AppareilService`. Apparently it returns `undefined` for your given `id` parameter when routing to _SingleAppareilComponent_ via `appareils/:id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Why does console show this error?

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
> at SingleAppareilComponent.ngOnInit (single-appareil.component.ts:19)

As [commented by jabaa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68941436/error-in-console-when-trying-to-route-to-404-page-in-angular/68943708#comment121839663_68941436), your a function inside your component returned `undefined`. Then an assignment tried to access a property on this non-existing object in the same erroneous **line 19**:
`this.name = this.appareilService.getApparreilById(+id).name`

#### How to debug this?

- open your browser's dev tools, go to the debugger, set a breakpoint on the erroneous line
- or add debug logging in your source code to show more details

In your `SingleAppareilComponent` try logging the `id` parameter extracted from current route-path as well as the return value of `getApparreilById(+id)`:

```js
    const id = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
    console.log('Routed to SingleAppareilComponent to display appareil with id: ', id)
    let appareil = this.appareilService.getApparreilById(+id);
    console.log('AppareilService returned appareil: ', appareil):
    this.name = appareil.name; // if appareil is undefined then you will get an error here
```

#### What possibly happened?

To analyze your issue further, we must see your `AppareilService` component, especially the method `getApparreilById`.

#### Test your service

```js
appareils = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Machine à laver',
    status: 'éteint'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Frigo',
    status: 'allumé'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Ordinateur',
    status: 'éteint'
  }
];

function getApparreilById(id) {
  const appareil = this.appareils.find(
    (appareilObject) => {
      return appareilObject.id === id;
    }
  );
  return appareil
}

/*  Tested with vairous inputs: if not found, then undefined!  */
console.log("getApparreilById(1) returns: ", getApparreilById(1));
console.log("getApparreilById(2) returns: ", getApparreilById(2));
console.log("getApparreilById(3) returns: ", getApparreilById(3));
console.log("getApparreilById(4) returns: ", getApparreilById(4));
console.log("getApparreilById('') returns: ", getApparreilById(''));
console.log("getApparreilById('1') returns: ", getApparreilById('1'));
```

So the [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method always returns `undefined` if *appareil* with specified `id` was not found.

And [`undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined) is just an identifier (or you could say a place-holder which signals "Uups, sorry: nothing, nada, null"). It has no properties (like *name*) to access.

so the error-message is:

> **Cannot read** property 'name' **of** undefined

There is an object `undefined`, but it has no properties, so you can not read or write any property.

#### Alternative way of returning

You could also return a **default value-object** which is *defined*, but with *empty* values, like:

```
getApparreilById(id: number) {
  const appareil = this.appareils.find(a => a.id === id);
  if (appareil === undefined) {
    return {id: 0, name: '', status: ''};  // defined but empty object
  }
  return appareil;
}
```

#### Assumption on a backend HTTP GET call

Assume the service tries to fetch the appareil resource with specified `id` from your backend, like: `GET /appareils/:id`
and expects either a response with HTTP status 200 and the appareil inside body.

Or like apparently here (in the unhappy case), a response with HTTP status 404 if appareil with specified id was not found on backend.

Then the body could be empty, so that `getApparreilById` returns an `undefined` appareil object. If no object, then no property `name`.

### Redirect to 404 page programmatically

If `undefined` is returned (signaling "appareil not found"), you could (as you probably intended) redirect to another component, e.g. your 404 page.

The path to your 404 page was defined inside the routes-definition of your app:

`{ path: 'not-found', component: FourOhFourComponent },`

You can then use Angular's `Router` inside your component `SingleAppareilComponent`:

```js
import { Router } from '@angular/router'; // import the router module here

export class SingleAppareilComponent implements OnInit {

  name: string = 'Appareil';
  status: string = 'Statut';

  // inject router in constructor as parameter 
  constructor(private appareilService: AppareilService,
              private route: ActivatedRoute,
              private _router: Router) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    const id = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
    let appareil = this.appareilService.getApparreilById(+id);

    if (typeof appareil === 'undefined') {
      // use router to redirect to 404 page as defined in your routes
      this._router.navigateByUrl('/not-found');
    }

    // else continue
    this.name = appareil.name;
    this.status = appareil.status;
  }
}
```

Note: the `get` method is only called once (better performance).
The undefined test can also be simplified to something like `myVar === undefined` (which should have same effect in most cases).

#### Alternative error handling

Another way would be to return a Promise from your service-method.
This would let you define callbacks for both cases (the happy 200, and all unhappy like 404).

See:
[Angular: Http vs fetch api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53660262/angular-http-vs-fetch-api)

#### Further reading

- [How can I check for "undefined" in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3390396/how-can-i-check-for-undefined-in-javascript#3390426)
- [How to redirect to another component after checking conditions in angular 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60226392/how-to-redirect-to-another-component-after-checking-conditions-in-angular-8)

Comment: thank you I've read your answer carefully and for your suggestions i'll try to read it more. But I still don't understand why the property "name" is undefined ? can you help me on that ? I added what you asked for in my initial question `AppareilService`. thanks a lot !!

Comment: Thanks for the comment, and `AppareilService` code in your question. I updated my answer and explained why the undefined is an error signal for "not found" rather  than an object with properties like "name". Click on the demo in section "Test your service" and read my advice below how you could return an __empty-object__ instead of undefined. Which then has a property "name".

Answer (score 0):

It actually mentions the exact line issue is on this line in ngOnInit:

```
    this.name = this.appareilService.getApparreilById(+id).name;
```

I suspect you are supposed to return an observable instead of a value  there and subscribe to it since how do you know your data is loaded when ngOnInit is called anw .

Comment: I agree with you, I'm pretty sure that this.appareilService.getAparrailById() is an Observable, so GooshFen should subscribe to it to get the response

Comment: I think it wasn't even an observable since it returned `undefined` but could be fixed  to return an observable that could give him data any time in the future(when they will get loaded) It's all about fixing the service to support async data  loading  and not depending on any value that exists  only at the time ngOnInit is called.

Comment: Only one case if there is no async call . Then  actually there was something not found in a local in memory collection, but we cannot  tell from the above code